# Extract files from a web archive (.warc)

Tags: website, archiving, webarchive

I have a number of web sites I am archiving in order to retain many of the linked files there, specifically a number of PDFs.

I haven't had a problem using the Heritrix crawler to collect the sites. However I haven't found a good solution to extracting the files from these `.warc` files.

Does any one have experience with this, or have a preferred way to get these individual files out?

Answer (score 6):

You could browse the WARC with [Webarchive Player](https://github.com/ikreymer/webarchiveplayer) and save the files you want from your browser. Alternatively, upload the WARC to [webrecorder.io](https://webrecorder.io) and browse/download there.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to try warctools  https://github.com/internetarchive/warctools it's python lib that is very easy to use.

Answer (score 4):

[ReplayWeb.page](https://github.com/webrecorder/replayweb.page) replaces Webrecorder Player which replaced WebArchivePlayer.

No app to install, just go to the page and browse to your file. All processing is local.

Answer (score 2):

I am using this project: https://github.com/chfoo/warcat

Example Run:

```
python3 -m warcat --help
python3 -m warcat list example/at.warc.gz
python3 -m warcat verify megawarc.warc.gz --progress
python3 -m warcat extract megawarc.warc.gz --output-dir /tmp/megawarc/ --progress
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I've found that [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html) by itself
often doesn't work, but there is a plugin called eDecoder for it that can be used to enable warc support.

eDecoder can be downloaded for free from [here](https://www.tc4shell.com/en/7zip/edecoder/).

Upon opening a warc with this plugin installed, it acts like any other archive in 7-Zip with a few exceptions:

- an extra column is added that shows the original URL of each file.
- each file gets prepended with a number to prevent filename collisions (eg `index.html` could get renamed to `000123 index.html`).
- folder structures are discarded, all of the files are visible in the main view regardless of what folder they were in originally, and there are in fact no folders at all.

While it can be downloaded for free, it does seem to be closed source, both in terms of the code and the license, and is therefore limited to Windows due to it being a compiled DLL.

Answer (score 0):

I've used 7-Zip before to extract individual files or whole archives from Web Archive format files.

It's available from their site [here](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html).

Comment: Interesting. I'm on a Linux machine so I used the **p7zip** build. It doesn't seem to recognize the ``.warc`` as any sort of archive it can decompress (``p7zip -d web-archive.warc``). You were able to pull individual files out with 7-Zip though?

Comment: @walker I was indeed.  Although the archive was not recognised, it did open with 7-Zip and the contents were displayed and were extracable.

Comment: Hm. I've gotten onto a Windows machine and am using 7-Zip 9.20. I have three different ``.warc`` files but none are extractable by the program. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: I find this works but only with specific file types like images and html. Some file types don't appear.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution suitable for terminal usage (Ubuntu). Unfortunately in my case (warc files created by using browsertrix-crawler) the previous answers did not work out.

I found [warc-extractor](https://github.com/recrm/ArchiveTools#warc-extractorpy) to work best in my case. It is a python tool and extracting all HTML pages is as easy as calling:

```
$ warc-extractor http:content-type:text/html -dump content -error
```

in the directory containing the `warc` files. I needed the `-error` flag as my crawls contain quite a few problematic pages. For my usecase it is sufficient to successfully extract the major part which this tool does well enough.